# What could the only answer to this question be?

Tags: lateral-thinking

You're not allowed to restate the question, or answer with a question. What could the answer be?

Comment: Wait what? Unclear? How?

Comment: Doorknob, who put this on hold, did not understand the puzzle :'D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There couldn't be any answers to this question because this question was put on hold by Doorknob.

From [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question):

> ### What does it mean for a question to be *closed*?
>
> When a question is closed, **no additional answers may be posted to it**,
>   although the question and existing answers can still be edited (by
>   users with edit privileges or by suggested edit) and voted upon, and
>   will continue to count for badges. The asker of a closed question may
>   still accept an answer.
>
> Closed questions can be re-opened by users who have sufficient
>   reputation.
>
> ### What does it mean for a question to be *on hold*?
>
> If a question has been closed, then for the first 5 days, it is marked
>   as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the
>   question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During
>   this period, if the question is edited <s>by the asker</s>
>   ([now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196026/nobody-in-my-community-has-the-power-to-re-open-a-question#comment618477_196026)
>   by anyone), it will be added to the [reopen
>   queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). **Other**
>   **than this, there is no functional difference between “on hold” and**
>   **“closed”**.

<sup><sup>Please not reopen the question or delete my answer because we all love fun :)</sup></sup>

Comment: LOL Not what I was expecting thanks to @Doorknob but I guess it'll do now.

Comment: Didn't you answer this question while it was on hold?

Comment: @warspyking - I was going to say the only possible answer is 'on hold', since any interesting lateral-thinking question like this will get some mod or other putting 'on hold' in the title after the question! (And the odds are this comment will mysteriously disappear too :-p )

Comment: @JulianRosen it's possible to answer closed questions about 2 hours after being closed with simple JS trick. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: What is wrong with my answer, let me know? It seems to be correct...

Comment: Nice sorcery trick here.